# How to develop a responsive web page

Tags: android, html, ios, css

This may be considered a broad topic. I hope not because I need a bit of guidance.

So when i'm developing a responsive webpage/website I drag my browser to certain viewport sizes (that are equal to device sizes) and add media queries in where needed.

In Google Chrome Dev tools you have the device emulator that allows you to toggle device mode by setting the browser to look like/act like an iPad, iPhone, Samsung etc.

My question, my site looks slightly different on the emulator then it does on the browser. Which should I use? The browser to build a responsive site or the Dev Tool emulator?

Comment: You're right...entirely too broad  and/or opinion based. Not a question suitable for SO.

Comment: You can't beat physical devices themselves for the only truly accurate reading.  There are quite a few ways in which emulators and desktop browser windows may give you different results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chrome dev tools to develop the grid, but keep checking on the iPad / Phone for details.

Resizing the window can also help to find gaps in the grid (Bootstrap...).